# PHP- Fatal error: Call to a member function dbRows() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm trying to download records from database on checkbox selection in excel format.  And I'm getting a Fatal error:

> Call to a member function dbRows() on a non-object.. on   $res =
>   $DB->dbRows($sql);

on the downloaded excel file.

```
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to mysql:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());


//$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE Delivery_no = '$_REQUEST[Delivery_no]'" ;


    $checks = implode(",",array_map('strval', $_REQUEST['check']));

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
        if(!empty($_POST['check'])) 
                    {


            global $DB; 
            header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            require_once 'protectExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
            require_once 'protectExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Favorite');
            /*$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:R1');*/
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','id');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1','Brand');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1','Bill_date');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1','Invoice_no');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1','Bill_to_party');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1','Product' );
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1','Category');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1','Category_product');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1','Barcode');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J1','Size');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K1','Shade');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L1','MRP');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M1','Quantity');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N1','Item_code');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('O1',' Material_desc');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('P1',' CD');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q1','TD');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('R1','SP.CD');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('S1','Rate');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('T1','Net_amount');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('U1','Delivery_no');

            $row =2;

            $sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName WHERE Delivery_no IN ($checks)" ;
            echo $sql;

            $result= @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());


            $res = $DB->dbRows($sql);



            foreach($res  as $d) {

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $d['id']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row, $d['Brand']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$row, $d['Bill_date']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$row, $d['Invoice_no']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$row, $d['Bill_to_party']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$row, $d['Product']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$row, $d['Category']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$row, $d['Category_product']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$row, $d['Barcode']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$row, $d['Size']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$row, $d['Shade']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$row, $d['MRP']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$row, $d['Quantity']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N'.$row, $d['Item_code']);            
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('O'.$row, $d['Material_desc']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('P'.$row, $d['CD']);            
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q'.$row, $d['TD']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('R'.$row, $d['SP.CD']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('S'.$row, $d['Rate']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('T'.$row, $d['Net_amount']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('U'.$row, $d['Delivery_no']);

                $row++;
            }
        } 

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        exit;   
    }
```

Comment: show what $checks is. an array i guess?

Comment: $checks = implode(",",array_map('doubleval', $_REQUEST['check']));

Comment: do a var_dump of this.

Comment: on $check or $res?

Comment: That code makes no sense at all. What is `$DB`? Looks like you are trying to mix some database abstraction class with primitive mysql queries.

Comment: $check. ALso show what $sql is. Please update your question with this. Do not post code in comments

Comment: okay wait.. I'll upload the whole code..

Comment: There are soo many unknowns here. what is $DB_TBLName?

Comment: looks like $DB is a variable. Why do you include it as $DB_TBLName. Your error should be here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: $DB_TBLName is the table name Akin

Answer (score 1):

PHP code is case sensitive.

You have your var `$Db = @mysql_select_db(...`.

But you try to call it `global $DB;` which just got `null` I guess. Since it is not defined.

Just try `global $Db;` 
or change initial instantiation to 
`$DB = @mysql_select_db(...`.

Hope that will help.

**Warning** Stop using `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. Learn `mysqli` and/or `PDO` functions.